# Two different colors

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The answer to this puzzle is a word.

---

[image]

Comment: there are 2 cells highlighted in red on the bottom left (8 and 14), is that a part of the puzzle or a visual mistake? I am asking because they are not very visible

Comment: @Minot It's a mistake

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two different colors, eh?
In a 7 by 6 grid?
Hmmm, looks suspiciously like...

> the game Connect Four!

On closer inspection, there is only one set of

> four in a row: the four diagonal yellows near the top right.    These are numbered 7 1 13 5... So our mystery word is GAME!  (Using numeric indexes into the alphabet).

Comment: But, but, but... the retrograde analysis doesn't work!